# Error building Player: Win32Exception:

Tags: java, android

first i had this error 
Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:/Users/CASA/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android-23\aapt.exe', CommandLine='package -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/CASA/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_', CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'

i moved the aapt  from build tools 23.0.1 to plataforms android 23  and then another error appeared

Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:/Users/CASA/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk\tools\apkbuilder.bat', CommandLine='"D:\alexander\Unity u\Temp/StagingArea/Package_unaligned.apk" -v -z "D:\alexander\Unity u\Temp/StagingArea/assets.ap_" -z "D:\alexander\Unity u\Temp/StagingArea/bin/resources.ap_" -nf "D:\alexander\Unity u\Temp/StagingArea/libs" -f "D:\alexander\Unity u\Temp/StagingArea/bin/classes.dex"', CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'
help!